# Codeblocks Windows and makefile generation C++

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks

Our teacher requires  us to submit a makefile with our Homeworks.  What exactly is the use of a makefile and how can I go about generating it through code blocks ?

Answer (score 1):

[These are Makefiles](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm). They serve as a guide for [the `make` utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) to build one's project. You typically "generate" one by knowing its syntax and writing it using a code editor.